# A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test: org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener

Tags: java, maven, surefire

I have a project which is packaged as an ear.  For the past month or so system tests have been disabled.  We turned them back on and have been fixing problems with failed tests and the build script.  I have not been able to crack the latest problem:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project systemTest: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test: org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.14.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit47/2.14.1/surefire-junit47-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-junit48/2.14.1/common-junit48-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-junit4/2.14.1/common-junit4-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-junit3/2.14.1/common-junit3-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-grouper/2.14.1/surefire-grouper-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.4/maven-shared-utils-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-java5/2.14.1/common-java5-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.14.1/maven-surefire-common-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.14.1/surefire-booter-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.14.1/surefire-api-2.14.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I can't figure out how org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener can't be found.  The whole project is build with maven and `junit` is included as a test dependency.

As far as we can tell, doing a full build works everywhere except on the build server.  Second interesting point, on the build server, everything builds fine when system tests aren't included and system tests work fine when run by themselves.  The problem only happens when the full project is built including the system tests.

This is the relevant portion of the `pom.xml` for the system tests

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>com/crowncastle/test/*Test.class</include>
            <include>com/crowncastle/test/suite/*TestSuite.class</include>
        </includes>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}ear${file.separator}src${file.separator}main${file.separator}application${file.separator}APP-INF${file.separator}classes</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}ff${file.separator}src${file.separator}main${file.separator}resources</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}ff${file.separator}target${file.separator}classes</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}ff${file.separator}target${file.separator}test-classes</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>900</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Update**
I thought perhaps there was an older version of `junit` hanging around that could be causing problems, so I ran `mvn dependency:analyze` and `mvn dependency:tree` but the only mention of `junit` is `junit 4.10`, which is the appropriate version.

**Update**
We were able to duplicate the problem on our test build server.  I didn't mention before that the developer workstations run windows 8 and the build server is linux.  So it could be a windows vs linux problem, but I don't see what.

Comment: Perhaps check you don't have a corrupt jar on the build server? It's also worth fixing the plugin versions in your build so they are consistent between environments.

Comment: You bring up a good point that perhaps you can help me with.  In googleing, some one said the wiped their local maven repo and that fixed a similar problem for them.  I didn't wipe it because I didn't want to affect other builds.  Instead I overrode the repo location via system parameters and then everything worked fine.  Since things worked in the new repo, I then tried wiping the original repository and building again, but this time the original error came back.  So, using a new location worked, but not deleting the original location.

Comment: Hmm. Dunno what that could be if you deleted the local repo and rebuilt it. I would check whether the jars match. If there are other builds, one may have a different remote repository setting, hence you get a different version of a jar in the local repo which is incompatible for some reason. It's unlikely but possible.

Comment: We did a bunch of rebuilds with different local repos on different systems and it doesn't appear that any of the jars are corrupt.  All sizes match.

Comment: is the output above from the debug output? It might not be the Junit class you're looking for: "A required class was missing while" is not a classnotfound exception. It may be some class needed to run. Maybe the wrong JDK? Have you tried another version of the surefire plugin?

Comment: We started with 2.12.1 and have upgraded to 2.14.1, but that didn't effect the resulting error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a combination of two factors:

First, there was a transitive dependency problem (namely that of hamcrest-core 1.1 -> jmock 1.1.0 ->  JUnit 3.8.1) where (in Maven's dependency-tree) the older JUnit was 'closer' to the systemTest module (which was inheriting the version dependency), and revision 3.8.1 of JUnit doesn't have contain org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener.

Second, there was confusion over the interpretation of the `<version>` tag by maven--  having `<version>4.10</version>` indicates a *soft* requirement for junit, rather than a hard requirement (which might be indicated with `<version>[4.10]</version>`
(see also [Maven Dependency Mediation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges)))

The latter led maven to accept the 'closest' satisfactory JUnit dependency (which in this case was 3.8) rather than the expected value, thereby giving rise to the error.  Altering the pom to the [N.mm] 'hard' syntax resolves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar issue today while rebuilding dev environment.
A handful of jars were downloaded incorrectly.  I was able to continue by spot-deleting the problem folders from my maven repository.  This forced maven to download them again, and then they worked without problem.

In this case I removed:

{local_repo}\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-surefire-plugin